# Align texts with different weight vertically

Tags: flutter

I want two texts with different weights to be aligned vertically. Currently what I get is that the bolder text get pushed down:

[image]

In my widget I've one row with 2 centered children. I've added a Center widget, but it doesn't helped at all:

```
                      Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'TEST',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                              )
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'TEXT',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
```

Comment: I created a new project and using Scaffold I puted your code in the body! Both texts are aligned vertically (no logo). Did you try?

Comment: I didn't use Scaffold. I have only MaterialApp and this widget is in home.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It was because the font was rendered somewhat strange. If I change the font to other font family, it aligns perfectly.

Comment: Great! I returned to work now and would try again.